# Minimum number of swaps

Tags: mathematics, optimization

This puzzle is related to [this math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4815377/573047).

Consider $4$ lists of integers: $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$, $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$, $(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$, $(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$ where order does not matter.

We want to apply repeatedly some swaps, i.e. exchange an element of a list with an element of another list, till the absolute difference between the sums of the elements of any two lists is not greater than $2$.

I have counted $9$ swaps to get a possible valid configuration:
$(0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2)$ (sum is $9$), $(0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)$ (sum is $11$), $(0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2)$ (sum is $10$), $(0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2)$ (sum is $10$), with maximum difference $11-9=2$.

Is it possible to obtain any valid configuration in less than $9$ swaps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> We can easily show that the sums must be between 9 and 11. (If a sum was 8, the most the other 3 could be is 10 for a max sum of sums of 38. If a sum was 12, the least the other 3 could be is 10 for a min sum of sums of 42.)
>
>
>   At least one swap must involve a 1 because the list of all 1s needs to have a larger sum. Intuitively, swaps involving 1s are inefficient though as they change the sums by less.
>
>
>   So, we can swap a 1 and a 2 to fix the 1 list. Then we can swap five 2s into the 0 list -- two from the list we already swapped a 1 into and 3 from the other. This leaves us with sums 9, 10, 10, 11 in 6 total swaps. The lists are: $(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)$; $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)$; $(0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)$; $(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)$
>
>
>   It can't be done in fewer swaps because reducing each 2 list from sum of 16 to 11 or less requires at least 3 swaps (and swapping between them doesn't help).

Comment: The solution here feels too systematic for this page. Are these type of "puzzles" common here?

Comment: @Cruncher since anyone can answer any puzzle here, that includes more formal solutions too. While it's usually not a requirement, it's always nice to see some proof of optimality in many math-based puzzles. But for this specific puzzle, it has a tag "optimization", which mentions "There should ideally be a provable best answer, to avoid making the puzzle into an [open-ended] game"